# If two functions are defined in terms of one another, can their composite be defined?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, function-and-relation-composition

Say $$f(x) = 3*g(x)$$ and $$g(x) = 3*f(x)$$
Is the function composition $f(g(x))$ defined?

Comment: $f(g(x)) = 3 g(g(x)) = 9 f(g(x)) = ...$

Comment: @DavidLui precisely what I find troublesome. Does that mean this situation genuinely cannot be defined? At what point in the definitions of the functions does the error occur? I’m assuming it’s defining each in terms of another, which, one step along the process, is defining the function in terms of itself.

Comment: @DavidLui I’m guessing this is invalid because f(g(x)) is f(3f(x)), which implies that for some x, f takes on a value equal to three times that same value.

Comment: @DavidLui though I’m not certain, it seems that maybe the prior observation implies that it is defined for x=0, since for all x, x(0) equals 0.

Comment: $f(x)=9f(x)$ so $f(x)=0$, and $g(x)=3f(x)=0$. And once $f$ and $g$ are known, no problem to compute $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$. Here, $g=f$ and $f\circ f=f$.

Comment: @AnneBauval what can we conclude from the fact that f(f(x)) is f(x)? Does this imply that f(x) can be defined as any constant function, or can something else be known or concluded?

Comment: $f$ has been computed previously: it is the constant function $x\mapsto0$ (well... if you accept that $9y=y\Rightarrow y=0$; it depends in which "set" $f$ is supposed to take its value but it holds for instance if that "set" is $\mathbb C$). This is why $f\circ f=f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that for $x\in\mathbb{R} $, $f(x) $ and $g(x) $ are defined. Then
$$
g(x) =\frac{f(x)} {3} \implies 3f(x) =\frac{f(x)}{3}
$$
$$ 
3f(x) =\frac{f(x)}{3} \implies 9f(x)=f(x)
$$
$$
9f(x)=f(x) \implies f(x) (9-1)=0
$$
Since $9-1=8\neq 0$, $f(x) =0$ which also implies $g(x) =0$.
Then $f(g(x)) =f(0)=0$. In fact, this is true for all
$$f(x) = ng(x) $$
$$g(x) = mf(x) $$
with $n, m \in \mathbb{R}$ and $nm \neq 1$.
If $nm =1$ then $f(x)=g(x) $ is not defined so $f(g(x)) =f(f(x)) $ is not defined.

Comment: Thank you! Is this related to any specific subset of mathematics? Or is this question just a one-off thought?

Comment: This only really worked because $\mathbb{R} $ is a field. Fields are algebraic structures that are seen in depth in an introductory abstract algebra class, but they are widely used in other areas of mathematics.